# Matlab code for an eigenvalue problem on a L-shape domain

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, eigenvalue, pde

I hava a Matlab code code

```
model = createpde();
geometryFromEdges(model,@lshapeg);

applyBoundaryCondition(model,"dirichlet", ...
                             "Edge",1:model.Geometry.NumEdges, ...
                             "u",0);

specifyCoefficients(model,"m",0,"d",1,"c",1,"a",0,"f",0);

r = [0 100];

generateMesh(model,"Hmax",0.05);
results = solvepdeeig(model,r);

length(results.Eigenvalues)

u = results.Eigenvectors;
pdeplot(model,"XYData",u(:,1),"ZData",u(:,1));
```

When I run this code several times, I got two different images
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkC2U.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X29Gx.png)
I expected to get the same result, I need this code for my task on an eigenvalue problem.
I don't know the reason why, can someone help me with that?
Thank you so much.

I tried to access all the functions and checked any inputs to make sure everything is alright.
I was expecting to get the same image and a list of eigenvalues.
In my task, I am trying to obtain an approximate solution of the eigenvalue problem and its approximate corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Seems like you obtain eigenvalues with different signs. You can use normalized vectors to compare the results.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do that?
Is there any thing need to be changed in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you normalize the eigenvectors and sort them based on eigenvalues, you should get consistent results in terms of the direction and magnitude of the plotted data.

Try this code:

```
model = createpde();
geometryFromEdges(model, @lshapeg);

applyBoundaryCondition(model, "dirichlet", ...
    "Edge", 1:model.Geometry.NumEdges, ...
    "u", 0);

specifyCoefficients(model, "m", 0, "d", 1, "c", 1, "a", 0, "f", 0);

r = [0 100];

generateMesh(model, "Hmax", 0.05);
results = solvepdeeig(model, r);

% Sort the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
[eigenvalues, idx] = sort(results.Eigenvalues);
eigenvectors = results.Eigenvectors(:, idx);

% Normalize the eigenvectors
normalized_eigenvectors = normalize(eigenvectors);

% Plot the first eigenvector
pdeplot(model, "XYData", normalized_eigenvectors(:, 1), "ZData", normalized_eigenvectors(:, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried the code. But it still results in two images, one is upward and the other is downward.